# Basic Quit Function in LOVE2D

Tags: lua, 2d, exit, love2d

I started using LOVE yesterday and I'm trying to code a basic quit function with LUA.

Here's my code

```
if function love.keyboard.getKey("q")
    function love.event.quit()
end
```

I've tried it with and without the functions.
When I run it, it gives me this error

Error

Syntax error: main.lua:1: '(' expected near 'love'

Traceback

[C]: at 0x7ff9037828f0

[C]: in function 'require'

[C]: in function 'xpcall'

[C]: in function 'xpcall'

Comment: It looks like you need to learn Lua with a [tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TutorialDirectory). We won't be able to walk you through basic syntax here. [This explains how `if` statements work.](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ControlStructureTutorial)

Comment: They've got examples on their wiki that show how.  --  https://love2d.org/wiki/love.keypressed#Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if function love.keyboard.getKey("q")
    function love.event.quit()
end
```

Is invalid Lua syntax.

function is a keyword that is used to define function value. It is not part of the if statement and not used in function calls.

an if statement looks like

```
if condition then
  -- block
end
```

`love.keyboard.getKey("q")` is not part of the love2d API.

What you want to do would probably be achieved by implementing a keypressed event handler.

Computer programs are not written by guessing some syntax and then asking for help.
Do a tutorial and read the Lua manual if you want to do anything useful with Lua.